# how can i pass an object between two separate html files using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass an object from a page in page1.html to page2.html using jquery. The existing solution has a 100s of pages so having a div for each page in the same file is not a practical option.

Content of Page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function (event) {
            alert("pagebeforeshow event fired - pageOne is about to be shown");
        });
        function switchPage() {
            $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "second.html", { role: "page", stuff: "456", reloadPage: true });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header Text</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Page One</p>
            <a href="second.html">Go to Page Two</a>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="switchPage()" />
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the contents of page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function (event) {
            alert("pagebeforeshow event fired - pageTwo is about to be shown");

        });

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', 'second.html', function (e, data) {
            alert("pageTwo alert"); // + data.prevPage.find('#test-input').val());
        });



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header Text</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Page Two</p>
            <a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Neither of the alerts in page2.html fire when the page is changed from the button click event and the pageOne message shows when clicking on the "a link"on page 1.

How can i make page2.html display its own alerts and grab the data being passed from page1 as I need to catch the data object being passed from page1 and react to its contents in page2.

Links i've looked at include:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/XyqvS/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_pagebeforeshow2

Answer (score 0):

1. The [`pagebeforeshow` event is deprecated](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) as of jQuery Mobile 1.4 (therefor you really shouldn't use it).
2. If you must use it - the general idea of the event is to trigger before the transitioning to the new **virtual page** (inside the same DOM layout), and not before switching between two real different html pages.
3. The event gets only 1 parameter (a function), so you can't do `.on('pagebeforeshow', 'second.html', function`

You can use cookies/localstorage to share data between two pages on the same domain, but your question is not so clear - what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi Dekel, i'm trying to pass an object between separate pages on mobile devices, without posting back to a webserver. For example page 1 would allow the user to enter some details and these details would be displayed/used on page 2

Comment: What exactly is this object?

Comment: a custom object that will contain information gathered on some of the previous pages

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly this custom object is... but you can use localstronge for that.

Comment: +1 Thanks, i'll look into the localStorage but have been told that its not always appropriate within the soluction

Comment: I'm still not so sure what you are trying to achieve, but localstorage is a great feature to use.